# Using Zapier to pass Google Form Leads to Custom CRM

Tags: webhooks, zapier

I'm trying to pass Google lead forms to a custom CRM via Zapier. I created a zap by using Webhook by Zapier (Trigger Event: Catch Hook). I need to pass 3 variables (first/last name + email). The test is ok.

On a second step, I need to create the post to pass all those data to the CRM. This is an example of post url to send the data: https://crm.xxx.com/api/leads/?api_id=xxx&api_key=xxx&first_name=xxx&last_name=xxx&email=xxx

Is anybody know how to create the post url from Zapier? Someone suggested to use Postman, but can't find it in apps list.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Post URL using the `Webhooks by Zapier`, 'POST' Action and then copy/paste your URL into the URL. Then replace each of the `xxx`'s with the corresponding parameter from the Trigger.

`https://crm.xxx.com/api/leads/?api_id=xxx&api_key=xxx&first_name={{136820117__firstName}}&last_name={{136820117__lastName}}&email={{136820117__email}}`